# Column width of a control inside a Jquery DataTable, plain css for jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

My table is using TwitterBootstrap:

```
   <table id="sDetails" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Checked</th>
                        <th>Comments</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach(var item in m.Items)
                     {
                     <tr>
                        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ItemKey)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Item)
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Comments)</td>
                     </tr>
                     }
                </tbody>
            </table>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {          /* Init the table*/
             $("#sDetails").dataTable({
                 "bFilter": false,
                 "bLengthChange": false,
                 "bRetrieve": false,
                 "bSortClasses": false,
                 "bPaginate": false,
                 "bInfo": false,
                 "bJQueryUI": false,
                 "bAutoWidth": false,
                 "aDataSort": false,
                 "asSorting": false,
                 "bSortable": false,
                 "aoColumns": [{ "sDom": false, "bSortable": false, sWidth: '15%' }, { "sDom": false, "bSortable": false, sWidth: '5%' }, { "sDom": false, "bSortable": false, sWidth: '80%' }]
            });
</script>
```

1) How specify width of TextBox control? 
2) How to remove the CSS for jQuery DataTable? (i.e on this Table)- There is no CSS on table in Google Chrome, But some default CSS is applied on Table in IE.

Answer (score 0):

To apply css to the `TextBox`, either globally apply a style to all textboxes inside your css file, or use the last parameter in `@Html.TextBoxFor` which is [HtmlAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703535%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and apply style.

To reset to default css in all browsers use [boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).